# We need a software that could allow us to manage our products in our production process

Tags: productivity

I am currently working in a little company (tannery) that is looking for a specific software about planning management. The way the tannery is working is the following : the “production” space is split into many areas that bears the name of each step whereby the skin go. The skins are ordered to slaughterhouses and go out of the tannery ready to get sent according the client’s orders.

So we order a lot of skins (let’s take for instance 300 leathers). This lot will be devided in order to answer our client’s orders that come everydays.

We still have an order management system, we also can see every order that are being done, shippings, etc… We need to get those data from our system (that is Exact Online) in order to shape them in a more readable way.

Practical example :
We order for a lot of 300 leathers,
We have to fulfill 10 orders that are stored in our managing system (Exact Online) :

- Company X orders for 30 full skins tanned by Y way,
- Company Z orders for 20 half-skins tanned by W way,
- etc...

Our problematic here is that we can’t follow the skins during the manufacturing process. If the company X calls us, we can’t tell him where is their order in the manufacturing process, we only can say “Doing”. Moreover, this is an obstacle for the resources management since some of the workers can be under or over-used.

To answer our need, we contacted a company near of us that came to make an audit on the functioning of the tannery. During the interview, this company showed evidence that their solution couldn’t fit our need, and they’ve oriented us to a MES (Manufacturing Execution System) solution. After many researches, I found that all of the solutions that I saw have very much functionalities that we don’t need. So I decided to come on stack exchange to have answers from peoples that may can help me.

To be clear, we need to :

1. Be able to get the orders from our management system, and to be able of shape them
2. Be able, with a planning, to quickly SEE every commands in the manufacturing process. This planning will cross the areas and the days of the week (see Screenshots).
3. In order to be able to do that, we would like to be able, via a simple system (like Drag & Drop) to move quickly the orders in this planning (Careful here : the software will be used by tanners that are very not familiar with IT in general, we need those manipulations to be very simple, et very lookable),
4. Print this planning at any moment.

To give you a visual idea of what we expect, I’ve pu some screenshots. This is not a requirement, but this is how we see this solution. If you know some softwares that look like this, we are not closed to any proposal.

Very thanks for the time you gave to this post, and sorry if you can identify some english mistaked, i'm not english native :)

[image: Orders]
[image: Manufacturing Process]